# Switch statement vs Enum variable

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum with the following scheme :

```
public enum Enum{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
    //...
}
```

In another class, I compute a `score` based on this enum.

**Which approach I should use and why ?**

**Solution 1:**

*I use a switch statement* :

```
public int score(Enum value)
{
    switch(value){
        case Enum.A:
            this.score *= 25;
            break;
        case Enum.B: 
            this.score *= 7;
            break;
        case Enum.C:
            this.score *= 2;
            break;
        //...
    }
    return this.score;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

*I add a variable to my Enum* :

```
public enum Enum{
    A(25),
    B(7),
    C(2),
    D(16),
    //...
    Z(100);

    private final int scoreMultiplier;

    Enum(int scoreMultiplier){
        this.scoreMultiplier = scoreMultiplier;
    }

    public int getScoreMultiplier(){return scoreMultiplier;}
}
```

And then, my score method :

```
public int score(Enum value)
{
    this.score *= value.getScoreMultiplier();
    return this.score;
}
```

Comment: The one you prefer.

Comment: If it makes sense to make the multiplier a property of the `Enum`, by all means do that. If not, another option is to have a `Map<Enum, Integer>`.

Comment: Or add a method to the Enum to do the math?

Comment: "In another class, I compute a score based on this enum" is the multiplier an intrinsic property of the enum, or is it something that only exists because of how you choose to use the enum?

Comment: @jhamon Thank you for your comment, each approach have cons. The first one use a switch statement which is not elegant when enum grows up. The latter can break encapsulation. For example if I have an Enum for each day (Monday, Tuesday, ...), a score multiplier should not be linked with this enum.

Comment: @jsheeran Thank you for your comment. This seems a good option too. I can use a static block to initialize my `Map<Enum, Integer>` in another class.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for your comment. In fact, it depends on the point of view I choose. For example, if I use an enum to define all cards of a standard 52-card deck. I can add a `cardID` variable which make sense for court/numbered card (1,2,3,...) but for face-card is it still relevant ? This is the problem I am facing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option: the visitor pattern.

Define a visitor interface:

```
public interface Visitor<RESULT> {
    RESULT visitA(ABCD a);

    RESULT visitB(ABCD b);

    RESULT visitC(ABCD c);

    RESULT visitD(ABCD d);
}
```

Make your enum accept the visitor:

```
public enum ABCD {
    A {
        @Override
        public <RESULT> RESULT accept(Visitor<RESULT> visitor) {
            return visitor.visitA(this);
        }
    },
    B {
        @Override
        public <RESULT> RESULT accept(Visitor<RESULT> visitor) {
            return visitor.visitB(this);
        }
    },
    C {
        @Override
        public <RESULT> RESULT accept(Visitor<RESULT> visitor) {
            return visitor.visitC(this);
        }
    },
    D {
        @Override
        public <RESULT> RESULT accept(Visitor<RESULT> visitor) {
            return visitor.visitD(this);
        }
    };

    public abstract <RESULT> RESULT accept(Visitor<RESULT> visitor);
}
```

No you can capture your enum-based functions as visitors. For instance calculating the score:

```
public static int score(ABCD abcd) {
    return abcd.accept(new Visitor<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer visitA(ABCD a) {
            return 25;
        }
        @Override
        public Integer visitB(ABCD b) {
            return 7;
        }
        @Override
        public Integer visitC(ABCD c) {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer visitD(ABCD d) {
            return 16;
        }
    });
}
```

From one side this provides certain safety in a sense that if you add new enum items, you'll need to extend the visitor interface with new `visitX` methods - and consequently all the existing visitor implementations.

From the other side you do not pollute your enum with the semantics of the operation you want to execute on the enum. If you will need to add more function to your enum, you won't need to extend it. Just write new visitor implementations.

Comment: Wow, I did not know this pattern. Thank you for your answer, I will try to implement it in my case. This also explains me how `FileVisitor` works! Thank you!

Comment: @JohannMARTINET It is not quite classic to use the visitor pattern with enums.